# How do I go about calculating the phase of a complex transfer function at 10 kHz?

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, passive-filter, network

I need to calculate the phase of this two-port network at 10 kHz (see below).

[image]

I found phasor by first finding Z_total by using the formula:

Z_total(series) = Z_R + Z_C + Z_L to give:

Z_total = -i/2pi x 10^4 x 2.2x10-6 + 370 + (2pi x 10^4 x 4.9x10-3)i

Z_total = 370 + 300.6418i

then,

phasor = tan^-1(img/real)

phasor = tan^-1(300.6418/370)

therefore phasor = 0.6823 radians

But the computer says this is incorrect. Can someone please explain where I went wrong thankyou.

Comment: You found the phase of the total impedance. You want the phase at Vout = Vin*Z_L/Z_total.

Answer (score 3):

Apply the voltage divider formula to obtain the output voltage as a function of the input voltage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that the transfer function of this circuit is given by:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{sL}}{\displaystyle\text{sL}+\text{R}+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{CLs}^2}{\displaystyle\text{CLs}^2+\text{CRs}+1}\tag1$$

So, we also get (\$\displaystyle\text{s}:=\text{j}\omega\$):

$$\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\text{CL}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2}{\displaystyle\text{CL}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)^2+\text{CR}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)+1}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{CL}\omega^2}{\displaystyle\text{CL}\omega^2-1-\text{CR}\omega\text{j}}\tag2$$

We now also get:

$$\left|\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=\frac{\displaystyle\text{CL}\omega^2}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\text{CL}\omega^2-1\right)^2+\left(\text{CR}\omega\right)^2}}\tag3$$

And, when \$\displaystyle\text{CL}\omega^2-1>0\$:

$$\arg\left(\space\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right)=\frac{\displaystyle3\pi}{\displaystyle2}+\arctan\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{CL}\omega^2-1}{\displaystyle\text{CR}\omega}\right)\tag4$$